# How do you pass labels to Google Cloud Logs Explorer through log4js-node?

Tags: node.js, logging, google-cloud-logging

I have successfully logged messages and their severity from a Node application to Google Cloud Platform's Logs Explorer (k8s with built in logging agent) using `log4js` npm library and the `log4js` features below. However, the labels object does not log.

**stdout appender**

```
"type": "stdout",
   "layout": {
      "type": "json"
   }
```

**addLayout()**

```
log4js.addLayout('json', () => {
  const foo = 'bar';
  const biz = 'baz';

  return (logEvent) => {
    const severity = logEvent.level.levelStr;

    const labels = {
      foo,
      biz,
    };

    const message = `[${logEvent.categoryName}] ${logEvent.data} [${logEvent.level}]`;

    const logEntry = { severity, message, ['logging.googleapis.com/labels']: labels };

    return JSON.stringify(logEntry);
  };
});
```

Following the [GCP documentation on structured logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging), I also tried using `labels` for the labels key like:

```
const logEntry = { severity, message, labels };
```

I could not find anything in `log4js` documents (or code) about passing a log entry through to cloud logging. How can I pass labels so that GCP will recognize them and log them either in top level `labels` or `labels` inside `jsonPayload` or `resource`:

```
{
  "insertId": "r286o2xnfzsq955d",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "labels": {},
    "message": "this is my test message"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "k8s_container",
    "labels": {
      "namespace_name": "development",
      "container_name": "myContainer",
      "project_id": "123abc",
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-09-15T18:29:41.020140836Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "labels": {
    "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name": "gke-machina...",
    "k8s-pod/app": "myApp",
    "k8s-pod/pod-template-hash": "123..."
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-09-15T18:30:00.835752120Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem; I needed to define the labels inline where as before I was defining them in the `addLayout` function but above `return (logEvent)`. And for GCP, `labels` is the correct key name.

```
log4js.addLayout('json', () => {

  return (logEvent) => {
    const severity = logEvent.level.levelStr;

    const labels = {
      foo: 'bar', // define inline here
      biz: 'baz',
    };

    const message = `[${logEvent.categoryName}] ${logEvent.data} [${logEvent.level}]`;

    const logEntry = { severity, message, labels };

    return JSON.stringify(logEntry);
  };
});
```